# Chat bot to annoy us with questions from SU

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is a proposal. We have chat bots that <strike>annoy us in</strike> feed AUGR with new questions tagged `ubuntu` from U&L. Why not have one that feeds from SU.

I noticed some useful questions on SU tagged Ubuntu, recieving a bit less attention. So this may probably help us help those seeking help.

Comment: U&L is the closest in scope to our site, which is why it was created in the first place. If people were interested in following Ubuntu on all sites they should use [this filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/45658/ubuntu-filter) which gets about 10 question an hour. Having this in the chat room would create more noise than is needed.

Comment: don't double vote, guys. upvote the one you like. and don't touch the other one. *please*

Answer (score 9):

### NO!! It wont be any useful, anyway.

Answer (score -5):

### YESSS! We cant live without it!!